# Setting timeout for Jodd Imap or Pop3

Tags: java, email, jodd

I'm using [Jodd Email](http://jodd.org/doc/email.html) library to send and receive emails. With Jodd `SmtpServer` I can set connection timeout. I have tried to read the documentation but I have not found anything. I would like to set a timeout with Imap or Pop3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just extend the e.g. `ImapServer` class and override the `createSessionProperties` method like this:

```
public class MyImapServer extend ImapServer {
    ...
    protected Properties createSessionProperties() {
        Properties props = super.createSessionProperties()
        props.setProperty("mail.imap.connectiontimeout", 123);
        return props;
    }
}
```

With migration to Java8 it's going to be even easier to do this, as we will provide the session properties with some fluent interface.

Timeout is rather commonly used, we might add direct support for it as well.

Comment: thanks .. just a question .. how long is the current timeout?

Comment: See [here](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/imap/package-summary.html) - default is infinite timeout.

Comment: Hey @afterbit, if this works for you, please mark it as an answer, for other people :)